# Create Choice Column via JSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am using JSOM to create columns in my lists and not having issues for text, user, or number columns, until I attempt to add a Choice Column.

I have been trying different methods, but can't get it to create the Choice Column. Here is my current code:

```
        var fieldCollection = newList.get_fields();

        //add extra fields (columns) to the list & any other info needed.
        fieldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Number" DisplayName="My Number" Name="MyNumber" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
        fieldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="Approval Status"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE><CHOICE>Approved</CHOICE><CHOICE>Rejected</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>"," Name="ApprovalStatus" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);

        context.load(fieldCollection);
```

Comment: What's with the `"," Name="ApprovalStatus" />'` at the end of your field xml? I would say that is your problem right there

Comment: That is the internal name of the field, where the display name is separate.

Comment: The XML should look like this: `<Field Type="Choice" Name="ApprovalStatus" DisplayName="Approval Status"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE><CHOICE>Approved</CHOICE><CHOICE>Rejected</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>`

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the field XML, it should look like this:

```
<Field Type="Choice" Name="ApprovalStatus" DisplayName="Approval Status"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE><CHOICE>Approved</CHOICE><CHOICE>Reject‌​ed</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sample below

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    //Geting reference to the list
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CustomList');

    // Get filed collection
    var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

    var f2 = clientContext.castTo(
                oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="choice" Name="fldchoice" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType),
                SP.FieldChoice);
    var choices = Array("Approved", "Rejected", "Progress");
    f2.set_choices(choices);
    f2.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("List Field Updated");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Source - http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2013/03/add-fields-to-sharepoint-2013-list.html

Comment: I saw that method, but it didn't fit within the method I am following. I can adjust but was hoping to keep it inline with  fieldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="Approval Status"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE><CHOICE>Approved</CHOICE><CHOICE>Rejected</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>"," Name="ApprovalStatus" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);